# Oracle/SQL: Split two inter-related lists into independent cohorts

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Say I have a table TB1, for the conditions defined, the list below is unique.
The products and emails is Many-to-Many relationship.

I am going to do a survey for the products consumers purchased.

```
Product   Email  
TV        a@server.com  
Fridge    a@server.com 
Fridge    b@server.com 
TV        c@server.com  
Cooler    c@server.com
```

The requirements are:

1. Each product couldn't be assigned to 2 surveys. Each survey could have multiple products. All customers who have purchased this product should be in the same survey.
2. Each customer couldn't be assigned to 2 surveys. Each survey could have multiple emails assigned. Each survey is sent to one person, asking how do you like the products listed.
3. This list is big. The problem is the email server could only handle, say 3000 emails at once. In the cases when there are 7000 unique emails(each email is asking question about all the products the customer bought) to be sent, three SurveyIDs needs to be created. It doesn't mean each has 3000 emails, but it has to meet requirement 1 and 2.

Note: each customer could buy at most 10 products.

**Question:** How to find out the cohorts of the (product,email) pairs that are independent from other cohorts so that all three requirements could be achieved using ORACLE functions?

In the above scenario, all the records are in one cohort. Either they would go together or 
not going anywhere.

This is only my thought of resolving the puzzle. If there is any other better idea please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand what output you would want given your sample data.  I'm also confused about what `surveyID` means-- you say initially that each product gets a `surveyID`.  But then you say that you need to create multiple `surveyID` values based on the number of emails sent which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following the question.  It sounds like you are saying that given your sample data, you'd want to assign every row a `survey` of 1.  If so, that means that your sample data doesn't help us much.  You'd need to give us sample data that you want broken up into multiple sets and tell us which rows you want to assign to which set.  In setting up the sample data, feel free to assume that the email server can only handle 3 emails rather than 3000 if that makes it easier to create sample data that needs to be broken up.